# How to convert a XML file into a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, xml, pandas

I want to convert the following XML file:

```
<data>
  <level_1 name="employment">
    <level_2 name="sub-employment">
      <indicator>ind1</indicator>
      <indicator>ind2</indicator>
    </level_2>
    <level_2 name="sub-employment2">
      <indicator>ind3</indicator>
    </level_2>
  </level_1>
  <level_1 name="health">
    <level_2 name="sub-health">
      <level_3 name="sub-sub-health">
        <indicator>ind4</indicator>
      </level_3>
    </level_2>
  </level_1>
</data>
```

into a Pandas dataframe with a result similar to:

```
  level_1   level_2         level_3        indicator

0  employment  sub-employment   None             ind1
1  employment  sub-employment   None             ind2    
2  employment  sub-employment2  None             ind3 
3  health      sub-health       sub-sub-health   ind4
```

I have used the following code after import xml.etree.cElementTree as et and import pandas as pd:

```
def getvalueofnode(node):
    """ return node text or None """
    return node.text if node is not None else None          
def main():
    """ main """
    parsed_xml = et.parse("tree.xml")
    dfcols = ['level_1', 'level_2', 'level_3', 'indicator']
    df_xml = pd.DataFrame(columns=dfcols)

    for node in parsed_xml.getroot():
        name = node.attrib.get('name')
        level_2 = node.find('level_2')
        level_3 = node.find('level_3')
        indicator = node.find('indicator')

        df_xml = df_xml.append(
            pd.Series([name, getvalueofnode(level_2), getvalueofnode(level_3),
                       getvalueofnode(indicator)], index=dfcols),
            ignore_index=True)     
    print(df_xml)     
main()
```

but I am getting the wrong result:

```
      level_1   level_2 level_3 indicator
0  employment  \n          None      None
1      health  \n          None      None
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please [edit] to _describe_ how your result is different from your desired result

Comment: I would recommend reading the following article: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's related to the issue you're having, but it's best not to repeatedly append to a DataFrame. You can make a list of tuples, a list of lists, etc. and then convert the entire thing to a DataFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the following function, creating a dictionary of ancestors,
starting from *node* upwards:

```
def parNames(node, root):
    names = {}
    while True:
        node = parentMap[node]
        if node is root:
            return names
        names[node.tag] = node.attrib['name']
```

It will be needed later. It uses *parentMap* dictionary, which will be
created soon.

Read your input file:

```
tree = et.parse('tree.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
```

The actual processing should start from creation of a **parent map**
- a dictionary, that for each node returns its parent:

```
parentMap = {}
for parent in root.iter():
    for child in parent:
        parentMap[child] = parent
```

To create source data for your DataFrame, run:

```
rows = []
for it in root.iter('indicator'):
    row = parNames(it, root)
    row[it.tag] = it.text
    rows.append(row)
```

This loop creates a list of dictionaries (data for each row).
Each row (a dictionary) contains:

- under *iterator* key - the text of respective node,
- under "parent" keys (*level_...*) *name* attributes of all
  parents (returned by *parNames* function).

The next step is to create the DataFrame:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(rows).fillna('').sort_index(axis=1)
```

And the only step to do is to move *indicator* column to the last position:

```
df2 = df2.reindex(df2.columns.drop('indicator')
    .append(pd.Index(['indicator'])),axis=1)
```